# What is disadvantages(cons) to use aws fargate and why my laravel app is slow on fargate vs elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

What is disadvantages to use aws fargate.

I am using laravel web app i have deployed it on Elastic beanstalk with RDS mysql server.

VS. docker container on aws fargate database is same RDS mysql.

Why EKS and fargate are slow compare to elastic beanstalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you compared how much memory/processors are being assigned to your service in Elastic Beanstalk and also in Fargate? [This article](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-ecs-supports-memory-and-cpu-limits-at-the-task-level/) could help.

Comment: thankyou so much for replay same one of frd also suggested to check so i will check it i think some memory leak is there. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

When you say slow I am assuming you are referring connection latency from your instance to RDS db. If so this is the order of AWS latencies; Regional, AZ.

Things to check:

- Fargate instance in the same region as the RDS db.
- Fargate instance in the same AZ as the RDS db.

Hope this helps.

Comment: same region and same AZ for all resources ....Elastic beanstalk , RDS AZ and ECS AZ